# How to destroy or dispose wordpress uploder/manager?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, uploads, media-library, media-modal

Can someone help me, I want to destroy my previous media uploder frame and remove all elements they have created to change the media file type but I cant do that, In last of my search, I have found in comments of media-editor.js and media-view.js from wordpress folder, they destroy the frame with ***dispose*** function, but after I copy that and follow it, the dispose do nothing. I think, dispose can run if some condition are met, but I dont know what is it, can someone help me? Thank you..

This is my code to make media uploder frame

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
function call_media_library() {
    var media_uploader;
    $j(document).on('click', '.video_media_btn', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var btn_uploader = $j(this);
        //change media type
        var med_type;
        if(btn_uploader.hasClass('mp4-media-btn')){
            media_type='video/mp4';
        }else if(btn_uploader.hasClass('webm-media-btn')){
            media_type='video/webm';
        }else if(btn_uploader.hasClass('ogg-media-btn')){
            media_type='video/ogv';
        }else{
            media_type='video';
        }
        //after I have call media uploader in twice the previous media_uploader cant destroy
        if (media_uploader) {
            //this is not working
            media_uploader.dispose();
        }
        media_uploader = wp.media({ 
            title: 'Upload media',
            library : { type : media_type},
            multiple: false
        }).on('select', function(e){
            // This will return the selected media from the Media Uploader, the result is an object
            var uploaded_media = media.state().get('selection').first();
            // Convert uploaded_media to a JSON object to make accessing it easier
            var media_url = uploaded_media.toJSON().url;
            // Assign the url value to the input field
            if(btn_uploader.hasClass('mp4-media-btn')){
                btn_uploader.parent().closest('.input-group.input-group-xs').siblings( '.input-media-display' ).find('.mp4-media-src').attr("src", media_url);
            }else if(btn_uploader.hasClass('webm-media-btn')){
                btn_uploader.parent().closest('.input-group.input-group-xs').siblings( '.input-media-display' ).find('.webm-media-src').attr("src", media_url);
            }else if(btn_uploader.hasClass('ogg-media-btn')){
                btn_uploader.parent().closest('.input-group.input-group-xs').siblings( '.input-media-display' ).find('.ogg-media-src').attr("src", media_url);
            }
            btn_uploader.parent().closest('.input-group.input-group-xs').siblings( '.input-media-display' ).find('video')[0].load();
        }).open();
    });
}
```

and this is my wp enqueue in function.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'insert_script_to_my_plugin' );
function insert_script_to_my_plugin(){
    wp_enqueue_media();
}
```

and this is code from wp-includes/js/media-editor.js

```
// Destroy the previous gallery frame.
                if ( this.frame ) {
                    this.frame.dispose();
                }
// Store the current frame.
                this.frame = wp.media({
                    frame:     'post',
                    state:     state,
                    title:     this.editTitle,
                    editing:   true,
                    multiple:  true,
                    selection: selection
                }).open();
```

Comment: I still waiting for answer, pls help me and thank you for ur help

Comment: You don't get an answer, because nobody can figure out the relation between your js code and what you are trying to enqueue. You probably need to take a look at how the [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) works. You are trying to call a PHP function wp_enqueue_media() in your wp_enqueue_scripts callback than enqueue a javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

If `frame` is an instance of `wp.media`, `frame.detach()` does the job for me.